# How to have a sites navigation menu on a search result page (Search this site)

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, search-results, modern-experience, navigation

One of our departments has a library that contains some documents. When they search it redirects them to the default search result page. But unfortunately the navigation menu is missing on a the search result  default page.

There use to be search results web parts in the older SharePoint version but not anymore.

How can I redirect to another page and have the navigation menu including the search results?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint online, navigation menu is not available on the default result results page and you cannot customize the this page to add custom navigation menu.

Also, there are OOTB search web parts in modern experience. However, you can install & use the PnP Modern Search web parts developed using SPFx in modern experience.

**Documentation**: [PnP Modern Search v4](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/)

You can then create a custom search box and search results page and connect them using these web parts:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Search box Web Part](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/usage/search-box/)

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. I though as much.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) & [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future. It also removes this question from "Unanswered Questions" list.